# OnClick used in anchor tag to pass data via Search String failing in IE8

Tags: javascript, url, internet-explorer-8, onclick, anchor

I have used the onclick event handler for some time to enable me pass a simple alphanumeric string from page to page within my website.

An example HTML link would be:

```
<a href="dir/newapge.html" onclick="idemo('dir/newpage.html'); return false;">
```

As the onclick returns false it causes the browser to ignore the href... which is there for the search engines to find.

My idemo function just adds the id to the URL as a query string as follows:

```
function idemo(whereto)
{
  location.href = whereto + "?" + escape(my_id_is);
}
```

The variable my_id_is has been declared and is set prior to this to a simple alphanumeric string such as "myId". It is displayed on the web page and debugging calls to alert() have confirmed that when idemo() is called that my_id_is correctly holds the expected string.

My problem is that with IE8 this very simple way of passing the Id to the new page does not always work. Sometimes, despite the call to idemo constructing the correct URL with the correct search string, the page displayed in IE8 does not include the search string... as if it has reverted to using the anchor tag href value.

So for example, instead of displaying the page "dir/newpage.html?myId" it simply displays "dir/newpage.html"... note without even the question mark character.

My code worked for previous versions of IE (I believe) and works for Firefox.

I guess my question boils down to... is it OK to pass data between web pages by setting location.href to a URL containing a query string from within an anchor tag onclick event handler, and if so can you think of any reason why IE8 would have a problem with it ?

Answer (score 0):

> which is there for the search engines to find.

You should never be making a website that acts differently for search engines and users.
The better crawlers (google for example) work hard to detect this sort of deceit and will penalise you heavily if found..

there shouldn't be anything wrong with passing info via location.href

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Just to mention that there is no search engine deciet. It is simply a way to pass data between pages on my website via the search string. I'd be interested to find a better way to do the same thing. I used to use frames may years ago, then when they went out of fashion I changed to using the search string. It seemed simple and it worked and still seems to work for everything except IE8. Regards, Mark

Comment: I gave up using onClick to pass informnation between pages on my website. The information was simple, just an affiliate Id. Oh for the good old days of frames ?

I was a little concerned that the only response to my cry for help was a suggestion that I was trying to deceive the search engines (which I was not). However that ended up being a very useful response. If "Waffle" thought that was what I was doing, then perhaps a search engine might think the same. So I changed the approach and now store the affiliate Id in a cookie and have removed the onclick code.